Does async and defer have an effect for DOMContentLoaded event?
I want to try a css framework called tenoxui. It says it uses DOM to give the styles, and its cool and works. But sometimes, I got delayed when rendering the styles. I try to add async and defer, but I think it's not change much. Does anyone tried TenoxUI? Also, this is my code :
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Document</title>
    <!-- tenoxui script -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tenoxui"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tenoxui/property"></script>
    <script async>
      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
        use({ property: [property] });
        tenoxui();
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body class="bg-#e0e4e7">
    <h1 class="tc-blue">Hello World!</h1>
  </body>
</html>

It's just a simple code, but if my app grew larger, it sometimes has like a flicker before the style applied. So, anyone can tell me does async or defer is needed in my case. Thanks .
I want a solution for a best way to deal with website styling with DOM manipulation, do DOMContentLoaded is the best because it will execute the style quickly after the DOM loaded? Or there's anything else for dealing with this? I mean, TenoxUI is great, but still not quite understand which best method to use.

<script> documentation

Not used tenoxui but instead of using DOMContentLoaded, could you try just putting the use and tenoxui command in a script tag just before the </body> tag, this allows the DOM to be loaded and you to execute your command in sync, this might prevent the flicker.

A CSS framework that is used via a <script> is suspicious, don't they offer a <link rel=stylesheet>?

@Bergi it's actually an utility-first css framework. It's using DOM manipulation for styling as I said before. The styles is generated from the class name, but it's applied directly to the element style/inline styles.
